# Centering text in an item in a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a flexbox set up in a row and centered to have divwords1 and div1image next to each other.  The problem is that the text is moved over but the actual text itself is not centered.  Any ideas?

https://codepen.io/CaptainMattyP/pen/oNXWxWG

```
      <div id="div1">
        <div id="divwords1">
          <h1>Let the Terror<br>commence!</h1>
          <p>Building on the overwhelming 
            success of our acclaimed Dark Terror<br>
            and Dual Dark amps, we’ve distilled<br>
            thousands of customer demands into<br>
            a pint-sized valve hybrid head –<br>
            the Micro Dark.
          </p>
          <a href="_target"><p id="buybutton">  Buy  </p></a>
        </div>
        <section>
          <img class="div1img" src="https://www.thomann.de/pics/bdb/369213/10582053_800.jpg" >
        </section>
      </div>
```

```
#div1 {
  background-color: white;
  height: 420px;  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 350px; 
}

#divwords1 {
  width: 20%; 
  padding-top: 60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center; 
  margin-right: 20px; 
}

.div1img {
  height: 80%; 
  float: center; 
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px; 
  margin-left: 100px; 
}

  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

Comment: It is centered, however you have `white-space: nowrap;` set on `#divwords1` causing words to not wrap naturally and overflow the container.  I would suggest removing `white-space: nowrap;` and increasing the width of `#divwords1`.

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks!